# Importing internal CA to Jenkins

Tags: java, ssl, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, self-signed

I'm trying to use a Jenkins job (pipeline) to read some information from a json endpoint and do something based on that information then.

The endpoint it is reading from is an internal one and the application is reachable via https with a certificate that is self-signed by our internal CA.

Here's the example code, that is run by the pipeline to parse the json:

`new JsonSlurper().parse(new URL('https://my.internal.url/info'))?.application?.git?.commit`

To make it a little more complex, I'm using a Java binary from the *Global Tool Configuration* in the pipeline as well.

When I run the pipeline, I get the follwing error:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    ...
Caused: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to process url: https://my.internal.url/info
    at groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseURL(JsonSlurper.java:416)
    at groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(JsonSlurper.java:379)
    ...
```

So now I'm trying to make this CA known to the JVM, that runs this code, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

I tried to download the pem-file for the root CA, add it to the system certs and then import this to the system-default `cacerts` file for java (`/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`) by doing the following:

```
curl -Lso /etc/ssl/certs/rootca1.pem "<DOWNLOAD LINK>" \
    && chmod 777 /etc/ssl/certs/rootca1.pem \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/ca-certificates/projectname \
    && cp /etc/ssl/certs/rootca1.pem /usr/share/ca-certificates/projectname/rootca1.crt \
    && echo "projectname/rootca1.crt" >> /etc/ca-certificates.conf \
    && update-ca-certificates -f
```

Afterwards, when I use a class to test ssl connections in java (like https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029) and run `java SSLPoke https://my.internal.url/info 443` I can successfully connect. The Jenkins pipeline still fails with the same error.

Then I figured, maybe the pipeline uses the java binary that is copied by the global tool configuration (even though this is not yet done in the Jenkinsfile) to the workspace, so I added the CA to the `cacerts` keystore of that *tool*, that is copied into the workspace (`$WORKSPACE/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jre/lib/security/cacerts`).

And again afterwards I can use that binary with the SSLPoke class to successfully connect to the URL, but the pipeline still fails...

So I am out of ideas now... Has anyone experienced similar problems and managed to fix them? Without moving to officially signed certificates (which are not an option for the internal urls for various reasons, not even *Let's Encrypt*).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not manage to fix this but we have a workaround in place. We put the certificate into the slave container and regularl install it in all our Java installations on all our nodes:

```
def jdksJava8 = ['Java 8', 'Java 8 Oracle']
def jdksJava11 = ['Java 11']

def nodeNames = env.'NODE_NAME' ? [env.'NODE_NAME'] : getNodeNames().sort().findAll { it.startsWith('my-node') }

stage 'Install myRootCA', {

    currentBuild.displayName = "${env.'BUILD_NUMBER'}: ${env.'NODE_NAME' ?: 'all nodes'}"

    parallel nodeNames.collectEntries { nodeName ->
        [
            (nodeName): {
                node nodeName, {
                    jdksJava8.each { jdkName ->
                        withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool jdkName}"]) {
                            sh '$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version'
                            sh script: '$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -delete -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -alias myRootCA', returnStatus: true
                            sh script: '$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -noprompt -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -alias myRootCA -file /usr/share/ca-certificates/myCompany/myRootCA.crt', returnStatus: true
                        }
                    }

                    jdksJava11.each { jdkName ->
                        withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool jdkName}"]) {
                            sh script: '$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -delete -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias myRootCA', returnStatus: true
                            sh script: '$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -importcert -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias myRootCA -file /usr/share/ca-certificates/myCompany/myRootCA.crt', returnStatus: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }

}

@NonCPS
def getNodeNames() {
    jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes.collect { node -> node.name }
}
```

A job with this script now runs every night. And in case we have to restart a node we run it manually afterwards to install the certificate back.

Answer (score 1):

So we managed to fix this issue. The problem was, that we did not make our proxy deliver the whole certificate chain. And other than browsers, the openssl binary for example (and therefore also Java implementations) are not able to load missing intermediate certificates on-the-fly.

So we created a certificate, that contains the whole certificate-chain (from leaf to root certificate) and now everything works fine.

Comment: Sadly the problem was not fixed. It was just part of the problem. The tool coming from Jenkins to the slave containers still do not have the root ca when the container is restarted. So I am still looking for a solution...

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: We did not find a proper solution. But we have a workaround in place for quiet some time now. I added it as an answer to this post. Hope this helps you as well!